# JoinTable doesn't have a regular Long id, but rather EmbeddedId instead, how do I create a Spring repository with that?

Tags: spring, hibernate, many-to-many, spring-rest

I've implemented @ManyToMany mapping with an EmbeddedId class, as per the example provided by @Vlad Mihalcea. It works, however I need to create and use Spring's REST repository for this JoinTable Entity.

Usually, I would do something like this to enable the repository:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "companyproducts", path = "companyproducts")
public interface CompanyProductRepository
    extends PagingAndSortingRepository<CompanyProduct, CompanyProduct.CompanyProductId> {

}
```

But, since in this Entity (JoinTable) I don't have a classic `id`, like this:

```
public class FooBar {
    ....

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;    

    ...
}
```

but instead I have:

```
public class FooBar {
    ....

    @EmbeddedId
    private FooBarId id;    

    ...
}
```

I cannot use `Long` or let's say `int` because the identifier is not of any of those types, it's basically of type `FooBarId`.

By the way, I will also provide most of that class:

```
@Embeddable
public class FooBarId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "foo_id")
    private Long fooId;

    @Column(name = "bar_id")
    private Long barId;

    private FooBarId() {}

    public FooBarId(Long fooId, Long barId) {
        this.fooId= fooId;
        this.barId= barId;
    }
...
}
```

I did try, of course, putting `FooBarId` instead of `Long` in the repository declaration, but then in my REST json response I get something like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/foobar/com.example.springrest.entities.foobarid@g43
```

(note the path to the class itself, not a numeral parameter, eg. 5).

My question is: Is it possible to use repositories with an `EmbeddedId` instead of `Long`, `int`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course

```
public interface FooBarRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<FooBar, FooBarId > { }
```

the id is the embeddable class so use that instead of the classic primitive.

the problem in the response is probably something related to your save/retrieve logic

**Edit**: based on the response being the class instead of the numeral i expect you retrieved the id from the repository, but you should obviously get the numerical value from the id since now that id is the embeddable class

Comment: Hmm, but when I take a look at the join table in the database itself, no numerical id was given to the records of this join table (only the two foreign keys are there, which is of course expected)
So I guess there's no chance I can have a numerical id in the response, since there isn't one in the db table?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how I can get numerical id from the current setup. I did try adding another numerical ID along these two FKs but that turned out impossible. In short: I want to be able to have CRUD operations exposed by the repository for a particular record of the join table. Since this table only has two FKs acting as it's PK and no numerical id - I doubt it is possible at all. I just need someone to confirm that.

Comment: I simply request it like: http://localhost:8080/api/companyproducts (I will update the repository declaration with annotations I have used)